# Find the principle value of $\arcsin(\sin23)$ and $\arcsin(\sin24),$ where both $23$ and $24$ are in radians.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $\arcsin(\sin23)$ and $\arcsin(\sin24),$ where both $23$ and $24$ are in radian.

I tried many times to evaluate $\arcsin(\sin23)$ and $\arcsin(\sin24)$ in the same way as the method given in [this link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1854359p12521620), but I am unable to follow his methods for $\arcsin(\sin23)$ and $\arcsin(\sin24).$

Please,help me to evaluate $\arcsin(\sin23)$ and $\arcsin(\sin24),$ using the method mentioned in the link.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I disagree.  The posting seems clear to me.

Comment: It would help us resolve your confusion if you would explain (in your original question, not as a comment) what you understand $23$ radians (or $24$ radians) to be, and how you understand the sine function. Do you think of angles as being the spread between two line segments emanating from a single point, or more generally as a kind of angular distance from some initial point on a circle? Do you think of sine as the ratio of two sides of a right triangle, or as a coordinate of a point on a circle? (There are other possibilities, but I judge these to  be the most likely in your case.)

Comment: @BrianTung Good comment.  See the back-and-forth comments following my *answer*.  It does seem that the OP (i.e. original poster) intends that the domain of the sine function are angles that are measured in radians rather than degrees.  Assuming so, this is consistent with my *answer* and the subsequent back-and-forth comments.

Comment: @BrianTung I am unsure whether it matters, but I suspect that the OP simply regards angles as "the spread between two line segments emanating from a single point".  My speculation is based on the idea that the typical use of the term *radians* is in *pre-Calculus* Analytical Geometry / Trigonometry.  For me personally, it wasn't until I started Calculus that I was exposed to the domain of the sine function being anything else.  My speculation could be mistaken.   ...see next comment

Comment: @BrianTung However, it is unclear to me whether it is relevant what the OP intends by his use of the term *angle*.  That is, the OP's posting suggests that the domain of the sine function is [Real Numbers] coupled with the *radians* unit of measure.  So, a case could be made that it doesn't matter what that is supposed to signify.  That is, the arcsine function can be computed without specifying what the OP intends by the use of the term *angle*.

Comment: @user2661923: It's possibly relevant insofar as a "spread" (not a precise term, but I couldn't come up with anything better at the time) is a function of the position of the arms. One would not generally call such an angle $23$ radians; it would instead be $8\pi-23 \approx 2.13$ radians. Such a conception of angle is common at the start, but it's harder to perceive the periodic nature of the sine function that way (and harder to interpret $\arcsin \sin 23$).

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-winded comment.

This is **not an answer**.

I am confused by your posting.

Suppose that $N$ is some (**known, fixed**) real number and you let $t = \sin(N)$.  Then, per the definition of the arcsin function, you are looking for some value $\theta$ such that $-(\pi/2) \leq \theta \leq (\pi/2)$ and such that $\sin(\theta) = t.$

You know that the sine function has a period of $(2\pi).$  So, the first thing to do is to compute

$$M = N - \left\{ ~2\pi \times \left\lfloor \frac{N}{2\pi}\right\rfloor ~\right\}.$$

This implies that

- $\sin(M) = \sin(N)$
- and that $0 \leq M < 2\pi.$

Then, it is required that

- $\sin(\theta) = \sin(M)$
- and that $-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2.$

$\underline{\text{Preliminary Result-1}}$
$\sin(\pi - M) = \sin(\pi)\cos(M) - \sin(M)\cos(\pi) = \sin(M).$

The computation of $\theta$ may then be broken down into $(3)$ cases:

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~~~0 \leq M \leq \pi/2}$ 
Simply set $\theta = M.$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~~~\pi/2 < M < 3\pi/2}$ 
Using Preliminary Result-1,
simply set $\theta = (\pi - M).$

$\underline{\text{Case 3:} ~~~3\pi/2 \leq M < 2\pi}$ 
Simply set $\theta = M - 2\pi.$

Comment: Sir, am talking about principle value.

Comment: @Debrogli I am assuming that by "*principle value*", you are referring to the value $(\theta)$ such that $\sin(\theta) = \sin(N)$ and such that $-(\pi/2) \leq \theta \leq (\pi/2).$  This is the definition of arcsine that I was taught.  If this is consistent with your use of the phrase "*principal value*", then my response pertains.  If it is not consistent with your use of the phrase "*principal value*", then please specify exactly what you intend by the phrase *principal value*.  Then, I will edit my response accordingly.

Comment: Yes, principle value means $-(\frac{\pi}{2})\le\theta\le(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: @Debrogli Then, my response pertains.  Have you found a flaw in my response where either $\sin(\theta) \neq \sin(N)$ or where it is not the case that $-(\pi/2) \leq \theta \leq (\pi/2)$?

Comment: Sir,I already have mentioned in my original question that both $23$ and $24$ are in radians,not in degrees.

Comment: @Debrogli My response **assumed** that $N$ is in radians, not degrees, which is consistent with your posting.  This explains why [1] I specified that the sine function has a period of $(2\pi)$ and [2] why it is required that $-(\pi/2) \leq \theta \leq (\pi/2).$  I consistently use real numbers  to represent radians, throughout my response.  For example, I use $N$ to refer to $N$ radians.  Similarly, I use $\theta$ to refer to $\theta$ radians.  Have you found an inconsistency in my response?

Comment: What is 'M' in your notation?

Comment: @Debrogli For any real number $r$, $\lfloor r\rfloor$ (i.e. the floor function) represents the largest integer $\leq r.$  $M$ represents the unique value within the range $0 \leq M < (2\pi)$ such that $N - M$ is a multiple of $(2\pi)$.  Perhaps I was faulty for assuming that you were familiar with the syntax $$\lfloor r \rfloor.$$